# How to make a fork of github repository but host it on my server and be able get updates from github repository?

Tags: git, github

There is github repository which has several forks. I want to make my own fork of it and host it on myserver. I also need to merge several forks into my fork. And finally want to get updates of original repository and those several forks to be able to merge these updates into my fork. **How do I do this?**

I've read some docs and lots of answers here and came up with such solution:

- I could do [a bare-clone and a mirror-push](https://help.github.com/articles/duplicating-a-repository). Then add remotes for the original repository and all forks as branches.

Is this a correct way?

Comment: So in other words: you want to create a repository with multiple remotes. What's the complication in doing that?

Comment: idk, I'm very new to git and trying to learn it. Is the solution I found correct?

Comment: I doubt it. In unambiguous terms what's your end goal? Why do you want "a free private fork"? Whenever someone asks whether some solution is appropriate for a simple "problem" - it begs the question: is it understood (by the asker or me, it's not clear which is more relevant)? I don't know what "a free private fork" is - git doesn't care where a remote repo is. There's a lot of general confusion IMO in the question e.g. `and all forks as branches` a fork is a _repository_ it can contain multiple branches; and you don't need to create local branches at all to reference/merge a remote branch.

Comment: I've tried to simplify the question. Is it clearer now?

Comment: I understand your question to effectively be "how can I use git?" because what you're describing would be considered normal usage.

Comment: +1 AD7six  Getavros, the question is "What are you trying to achieve"  forget git, gthub, forks and the like.  What business or personal goal or process are you trying to do.  Once we know the reason that you want to do all this work we can suggest am appropriate approach.

Comment: @MichaelDurrant, I want to make a program which is based(uses source code) of several other programs which are modified copies of original program. And I want to include future bugfixes from these other programs into my program.

Comment: Then don't use Git as the solution to your problem. If you want to create a new software based on several other projects, find a way in your programming language to include these as modules/libraries from the source, not your own repo. If you need some changes to these libraries, find a way in your programming language to add it without changing their code. Otherwise maintenance will become difficult because you have to track, update and adjust so many components yourself.